# jquery code is not working when added data-input mask attribute in the inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('#dynamic_field2').append('<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"   data-inputmask="'alias': 'date'" name="reg_bdate" data-mask placeholder="Birth Date">');
```

when the button was clicked this should append in the dynamic_field2 div but it give's me this error
[image]

and I can't figure out how to fix this thank you.

Comment: Check your quotes (hence the red border)

Comment: I've formatted the code in the question properly, which nicely highlights your quoting error.

Comment: You have mis-matched quotes in the string you're appending. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $('#dynamic_field2').append('<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"   data-inputmask="'alias':'date'" name="reg_bdate" data-mask placeholder="Birth Date">');
> ```

Your quotation marks are either not escaped or you are trying to insert variables

---

Correct quotation marks:

```
$('#dynamic_field2').append('<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"   data-inputmask="\'alias\':\'date\'" name="reg_bdate" data-mask placeholder="Birth Date">');
```

---

Variables:

```
$('#dynamic_field2').append('<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"   data-inputmask="'+ alias +':'+ date +'" name="reg_bdate" data-mask placeholder="Birth Date">');
```